# Choosing animations used in Android Webview to gain high performance

Tags: android, svg, android-webview, vector-graphics, performance

Let me explain our situation first,

We plan to develop a web application by using webview component which will work on tablet devices (target device specification: Android 3.0, Dual Core Processor (1GHz x 2), 10.1"WXGA, 1GB RAM).

In the application there will be 2D animations and we design a character. Like,

- This character may wear different things, may change mimics
- This character may walk with these artifacts (over a fix background image)

Application will use local resources.

**My Questions are,**

1) Which tools will be best to show these animations considering **performance in webview** and **less resources size**.

- Canvas
- SVG
- Pure javascript by using fix images or animated gifs
- Or something else? *(Note: We do not want to use flash)*

2) Which development environment(s), tool(s) do you suggest to construct these animations and related resources?

*This is my first post in stackoverflow.
I hope this post and answers may help other developers also...
Best Regards,*

Answer (score 0):

Canvas would be better when we count in performance and SVG is something you can't render truly in all of the browsers, coz in previous versions of android SVG is not enabled by default you have to do a workaround on it to get it worked. Canvas is best tool  as you can render it in most of the browsers and considering performance in webview. any how android 3.0 onwards ther's a support for SVG.